# jQueryMobile - unable to link to PDF documents

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm unable to link to PDF documents on a mobile site using jQueryMobile.

The link is opened with the jQueryMobile-effects and displays a page with the text "undefined".

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add data-ajax=false to your link `<a href="your.pdf" data-ajax="false">pdf</a>` Since pdf is not supported on alot of phones you may want to explore something like this http://www.labnol.org/gadgets/ipod/read-pdf-text-email-on-ipod-mobile-phone/1929/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider integrating in pdf.js.  It seems to be an option considering some mobile devices don't directly support pdf's.

http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/